# Cloud Composer / Airflow: Relationships can only be set between Operators; received PythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We have several Airflow DAGs in Cloud Composer that previously worked fine. The code for the DAGs and Operators has not been changed, but after a recent deployment, we now get this error from the DAGs:

> Broken DAG: [...] Relationships can
>   only be set between Operators; received PythonOperator

Again, that DAG has not been changed for several weeks and was previously working fine.

The `PythonOperator` there is the PythonOperator provided by Airflow, imported like this:

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
```

And used in the DAG like this:

```
OPERATOR_READ_HEADER = PythonOperator(
    task_id='read_header',
    params={'object_name': 'dependencies/MT940 Header.txt'},
    python_callable=read_object,
    provide_context=True
)

SENSOR_INPUT_FILE_PROVIDED >> OPERATOR_READ_HEADER
```

Why would this error have started occurring?

This is on Airflow `1.9.0-composer` in Google Cloud Composer.

Comment: Looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336037/airflow-error-importing-dag-using-plugin-relationships-can-only-be-set-between)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug introduced in composer-1.4.2 release which we have fixed by now, try create a new Composer environment and that DAG error should go away. Meanwhile, we'll also apply that fix automatically on existing 1.4.2 environments automatically over the next few days.

Comment: If you don't want to wait on the auto fix rollout or create a new environment, you may apply the fix manually by running the following commands in your Composer GKE cluster:
`kubectl get deployment airflow-scheduler -o yaml | sed -e 's/cloud_composer_service_2019-01-10-RC0/cloud_composer_service_2019-01-10-RC1/'|kubectl replace --force -f -`

`kubectl get deployment airflow-worker -o yaml | sed -e 's/cloud_composer_service_2019-01-10-RC0/cloud_composer_service_2019-01-10-RC1/'|kubectl replace --force -f -`